# Does an old string object become garbage collected after calling ToUpper(), etc.?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Does this cause the old string object to be garbage collected or is it still the same reference to the same object?

```
    string str = "Hello World!"; 
    str = str.ToUpper();
```

I understand what the GC does and its unpredictability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Yes, the old string object will be garbage collected as eventually, the GC will find out that there are no more references to that object</s>.

After some research, it seems that string literals e.g. `"Hello World!"` are interned by default so even if there is no longer any reference to them they will not be garbage collected as @Henk Holterman has also mentioned in the comments.

This is because string literals are part of the assembly and there's no garbage collection for that.

So, I now rephrase my above paragraph to:

Yes, the old string object will be garbage collected if *it's not a string literal* as eventually, the GC will find out that there are no more references to that object

However, *when* the GC does this is *non-deterministic*.

Comment: Thanks. If I can extend this question then: If you create your own vector class for 3d graphics, and have thousands of them changing using the rule of immutability, and have thousands also being garbage collected, is this a performance issue? I guess structs would be more useful here so they're not referenced.

Comment: yes value types eat up less memory than reference types. in all honesty, you'll need to _measure_, _measure_ and _measure_.

Comment: With common sense, too, on whether reference or value types are more efficient for the given purpose. Thanks.

Comment: @PhilC: in modern GCs and memory allocators, allocating short-lived temporary objects is as fast as stack allocation and faster than `malloc`. And collecting them is essentially free (the algorithms usually used for the nursery / Gen 0 are typically O(#live objects), so dead objects have zero cost).

Comment: A _string constant_ like `"Hello World!"` will not be colelcted at all.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks for your feedback, I have now updated the post.

Answer (score 6):

> Does this cause the old string object to be garbage collected

We can't say. For two reasons:

1. We don't know whether there are other references to the string. If there are other references to the string, then the string won't be eligible for collection. Note: if the code you showed is the *entire* code, then there will not be another reference.
2. Even if the string is eligible for garbage collection, there is no way of knowing when the garbage collector will run. We don't even know whether the garbage collector will run at all.

> or is it still the same reference to the same object?

No. You created a new string. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper) *clearly* states (**bold** emphasis mine):

> Returns a **copy** of this string converted to uppercase.

and

> *Note*: This method **does not modify** the value of the current instance. Instead, it **returns a new string** in which all characters in the current instance are converted to uppercase.

Also, `string` is immutable, so it *cannot* be changed anyway.

Comment: Your answer would be much more compete if you added string interning remarks.

Comment: Is that guaranteed by the C♯ spec or is it a private internal implementation detail of some implementation?

Comment: @HenkHolterman we can consider non-existing abstract Framework or existing overwhelmingly popular Microsoft implementations. I prefer the latter.

Comment: @KonradKokosa - the argument still holds. Interning  is not relevant here, in nay framework.

Comment: @KonradKokosa: I looked at the Microsoft C♯ spec, not the ECMA one, and I *still* couldn't find anything in there about string interning. I was looking in the chapter about the `string` type, should I look somewhere else? Can you point me to the specification about string interning in C♯? I must admit that I only looked at the C♯ 6.0 draft spec, since there doesn't exist a newer one. Is that a new addition to the language?

Comment: @jörg-w-mittag string interning is more runtime's attribute, not the language itself. I do not remember what ECMA says about it and does not have it at hand now unfortunately . I am referring to the current implementation found in CoreCLR.

Comment: @KonradKokosa: If what you say is true, then string interning is completely irrelevant, since the question is asking about C♯, not the CoreCLR.

Comment: @jörg-w-mittag the question is about GC, not C# :)

Answer (score 0):

We can not speak about what the GC does and does not at any given time. We can only speak about what it **could** do at any given time, based on strong refernces. And of course with String, a lot of special handling comes into the room.

The general rule is "The GC can collect anything that does not have unbroken chain of strong references to the Root References". By design, Strings have been made inmutable. It is not a common behavior for classes, but has advantages in Multithreading Scenarios to do so. So ToUpper() will indeed try to create a new string instance that is propably not related to the old one. At a primitive glance as long as you stopped having hte reference to the old string, it should be eligible for Garbage Collection.

Except: String Interning. As the inmutable nature of strings can cause excessive memory allocations (each connaction operation would leave a garbage string in memory), there is a mechanic call "string interning" in place. Basically the framework has list of all strings already allocated. And if you try to allocate the same string twice, there is a decent chance the instance you already have in memory will be re-used. There will not be a new instance, but a instance will be re-used.

If you write the String "Hellow World" on 100 labels, there is a decent chance that between Compiler Optimisations and Interning there is actually **only one** string "Hello World" allocated in memory. In general the memory optimisation from String Interning is very good. But when you need to get around it (and other automatics/properties regarding string), they invented a extra class for that - [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Comment: Your remark regarding string interning is incorrect. String literals ale interned but dynamic ones are not - you may intern them explicitly through string.Intern call.

Comment: @KonradKokosa: Are you certain about that? The defintion of String.Intern says interning affects all "unique literal string declared or created programmatically in your program". And the only example is it being used on a StringBuilder return to get it into the Intern Pool. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx#Remarks

Comment: `String.Intern` will intern both literals or created programmatically strings.I was refering to the part where you suggest that any string programmatically created will (or may be) interned - which is not true.

Comment: @KonradKokosa: I read it so that the Runtime already interns both Literal and Programmatically created strings. Intern is for the 1:1000 case that did not happen (like if the string came from a StringBuilder wich is there to get around stuff like interning). Of course I might be wrong here, I have issues finding a confirmation.

Comment: nope, checking against intern pool while each and every string is being created would outweigh the benefits of interning (imagine you have millions of different strings already created and you have to scan them every time). Here is a nice use case: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/02/12/string-interning-effective-memory-management-with-dotmemory/

Answer (score -1):

Another detail, specific only to the `String` type and not other types is *interning*.  Basically, since strings are used so much, the runtime will only store one copy of each `String` value used, and since strings are immutable, any references to a string of the same value will be references to that same instance. See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/what-is-string-interning/